# sort data for database php

Tags: php

hey say I have a file containing something like this

```
name1 lastname1 email1 date1
name2 lastname2 email2 date2
name3 lastname3 email3 date3
```

what would the most efficient way to go through it to retrieve the first name last name email and date be? Would just exploding on a new line and then exploding those results on a space be sufficient?

Comment: By doing an expldoe, you have to be sure that there's no extra space. Sometime, in some file like that, you can have values in quotes, with space inside : "name 1" "lastn ame1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is effectively a CSV file, using a space character as a delimiter.  You can use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) and set the delimiter option:

```
$fh = fopen('data.csv', 'r');

while ($row = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ' ')) {
    // $row[0] is firstname
    // $row[1] is lastname
    // $row[2] is email
    // $row[3] is date
}
```

It would probably be a better idea to use a different character for delimiting, such as a comma, a tab, or a pipe `|`.

Answer (score 3):

What's the size of your file ? Different approach is needed, regarding `simplicity of the code` VS `memory usage`.

If it is a medium file (small, use the `file` function :

```
// file : Reads entire file into an array
$fileAsArray = file($filname);

foreach($fileAsArray as $line){

  list($name,$lastname,$email,$date) = explode(" ",$line);

  //do something with $name,$lastname,$email,$date
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would probably be to use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) specifying a space character as your delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

if it's a CSV file, use [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Assuming the separator is the TAB character :

```
<?php
$keys = array('name1', 'lastname1', 'email1', 'date1');
$entries = array();
$fh = fopen("test.csv", "r");
while ($data = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, "\t")) {
    $entries = array_combine($keys, $data);
}
fclose($fh);

var_dump($entries);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `fgets()` for reading each line and `explode()` on spaces.